# Are you allowed to have a module identifier be the same as the module type in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For example

```
module top
    debouncer debouncer(...);
endmodule

module debouncer
...
endmodule
```

Can I instantiate a debouncer as "debouncer" in the top module, or is that illegal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is legal for a module **instance** name to match the **module** name in Verilog, and it is quite common to do so when you only need one instance of a module.  But, you could have quickly verified that for yourself by simply compiling your file with your favorite simulator. The following is legal syntax and compiles for me:

```
module top;
    debouncer debouncer();
endmodule

module debouncer;
endmodule
```